# Error in accessing Hash key

Tags: perl

Here's my code..I am trying to create a hash lookup table and access the data from it in every loop..

```
 #! usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

sub bin2dec 
{
     return unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . shift, -32)));
}

while(<>)
{

    if(/SIB_DBG/)
    {
        if(/TTRB:\s*([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)/ ||
        /ETRB:\s*([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)/ ||
        /Command\sETRB\s*([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)\s([\da-f]+)/   )
        {
            print "$_ $1 $2 $3 $4\n";
            my $deci1 = hex($1);
            my $deci2 = hex($2);
            my $deci3 = hex($3);
            my $deci4 = hex($4);

            my $bin = reverse sprintf("%032b",$deci4);   #convert to 32 bit binary and reverse
            print "\nbinary :$bin\n";
            my $sub = substr($bin ,16,6);                #extract required 6 bits
            print "string :$sub\n";

            my $type = bin2dec($sub);                    
            my $val = $trb{"$type"};              
            print "TRB type: $type\n";
            print "detail: $val\n";

        }
    }
}

my %trb = (
0 => "reserved",
32 => "transfer event",
48 => "vendor defined");
```

but I am getting an error even if I have declared trb .

> Global symbol "%trb" requires explicit package name at script.plx line 31.
>   Execution of script.plx aborted due to compilation errors.

Again my input log file is like

```
Aug 31 15:25:53 usb3 kernel: [   78.684054] SIB_DBG TTRB:00000000 00000000 00000000 00002401, PTR: ffff88005ff8b000
Aug 31 15:25:53 usb3 kernel: [   78.815428] SIB_DBG ETRB: 5ff8b850 00000000 01000000 01018001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the hash %trb in this line:

```
        my $val = $trb{"$type"};
```

before you have declared %trb here:

```
my %trb = (
0 => "reserved",
32 => "transfer event",
48 => "vendor defined");
```

Move that declaration of %trb up above the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The hash `%trb` must be declared before it is used. Move its definition up to before the `while` statement -- after your subroutine defintion and all will be well

You appear to be more familiar with a different language, as you usually find Perl subroutines at the end of the program, but it doesn't matter either way